# How to change default :id in address to :filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Hi I am new to Rails and I'm looking for solution for how to change the default address

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/files/5
```

to

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/files/filename
```

or

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/files/5+filename+sometext
```

I am using ActiveStorage to store files and I would prefer to use filename from blob table.

Where might I find a solution? Routes?

Comment: My suggestion plz use carriwave https://medium.com/@mauddev/rails-5-and-carrierwave-53960ec20c4b

Answer (score 0):

I think https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes holds the answer you want.

You need a non-resourceful dynamic route.

```rb
get 'files/:file_name', to: 'files#serve_file' # , constraints: { file_name: /regex_here/ }
```

Then 'files/your_file_name' will route to the files controller's serve_file action and params will have { file_name: 'your_file_name' }. Then you can handle serving the file as appropriate.

Make sure to put this route above your `resources :files` otherwise I believe it won't work and be aware that this route will block some of the resourceful routes. For example, the url 'files/new' would be routed to files#serve_file with params: { file_name: 'new' }.

One solution would be to add a extra static segment to the route.

```rb
get 'files/serve/:file_name', to: 'files#serve_file'
```

Also be aware, from the documentation:

> By default, dynamic segments don't accept dots - this is because the
>   dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a
>   dot within a dynamic segment, add a constraint that overrides this –
>   for example, id: /[^/]+/ allows anything except a slash.